# woocommerce add Image Variation Swatches

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a color variation using jquery colorpicker. Now I need to create image variation. So if I'm right, I need to add image loader field, in woocommerce add variation form and then output this image on product page. 
So I don't ask you to give me complete solution. I just want to ask, may be someone can give me some example or information to read. And also, can I do this only using jQuery or I need to have knowledge in PHP too. Also I add screen's where I need to insert image load field. This is admin page in wordpress

[image: Admin panel]

[image: Product page]

Comment: [Variation Swatches and Photos](http://www.woothemes.com/products/variation-swatches-and-photos/) does exactly what you describe.

Comment: Yes I know. I will not pay, I need only add image field and retrieve image on product page. Also I already have color output. Now I need only image.

Comment: You aren't showing any code or asking a specific question, but we're supposed to just give you the same code for free?

Comment: You are right. But I don't know from what start. How to add specific field, that will upload image. I didn't do it before.